# ASP.NET MVC 3 Authentication/Authorization

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication, authorization

I am very new to ASP.NET MVC 3 (and MVC in general for that matter).  In ASP.NET Web Forms, I did authentication using Principals and Identities.  Is this the recommended way to do it in MVC or is there something newer?  I see a Membership class, but if I understand it correctly it is too heavyweight for what I need.

Does any one have a good tutorial or site recommendation to help me out with this?  It can be comprehensive as I still don't have this stuff solidified.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

FYI, here's a nice blog post about how to integrate IIdentity and IPrincipal with MVC 3

http://www.bradygaster.com/post/custom-authentication-with-mvc-3.0