# What is the best way for this authorization scenario?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 app and another app in another technology.

Basically a user can log in only on the 2 app. When the user login the app inserts a row in a database with the user id, the session id, the session creation date and the user host address.

When my user wants to go to the first app he clicks on a link where there is the session id ('MyController/AnAction?SessionID= 9d8bd5be-1e7c-4f32-96bc-3067efb0cf77').

The ASP.NET MVC would authorize/deny the session.

How can I implement this on the ASP.NET MVC side? I read some stuff about `AutorizeAttribute`, `MembershipProvider`, but I can't find my solution.

For instance I did the code that'll check the session, but I can't find where I can set `MyController.User`.

Answer (score 0):

[ASP.NET MVC 3 Authentication/Authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5748726/asp-net-mvc-3-authentication-authorization)

The first answer:
http://www.bradygaster.com/custom-authentication-with-mvc-3.0

Comment: bradygaster is here using a form authentication, and there is no forms on my asp.net mvc app, the user already entered his informations on the second app.